# If I am using 400 images within my iOS app how should I package them?

Tags: ios, image, data-storage

I am currently including roughly 400 images within my app. (Each entity has it's own image). Should I just include them in the App Bundle and leave it at that? Or, should I save them in binary form in Core Data? I'm asking because right now my App is currently above the 50mb for downloading from the App Store and I want it to be below that so my users don't have to be on wifi to get my app. Will my app size be smaller if I include them in binary form and not in the app bundle?

Comment: Your app will probably be bigger if you put all of the image data in the database due to the overhead of the database. Make the images smaller or maybe have the app download them the first time the app is run.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy that makes sense, I'll probably do the download at first run option. Cheers.